# Drupal 7: Footer not shown in Arabic page (thought in English and Hebrew yes)

Tags: drupal-7, footer

I am working with Drupal - Seven theme.

I am editing a website that is multilangual: English and Hebrew, I want to add Arabic.

I am facing a problem with the footer menu block:
I add to the English and Hebrew footer menu 'links' for Arabic, exactly the same way English and Hebrew were added (or, exactly the same way English was added to Hebrew).
But I can't see the footer in the Arabic page.

when I look at the Developer Console, I see the following empty content (in contrast to Hebrew and English):

```
<div id="footer-wrapper">
 <div id="footer" class="clearfix">    
 </div>
</div>
```

What am I missing? was anything edited manually

Comment: Blocks are rendered by [`block_page_build()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!block!block.module/function/block_page_build/7). Have you looked into this function to try to determine why the block is not being displayed?

Comment: there is nothing related to footer there.
i think the problem is language related, there must be a place where it is disabled for one language and enabled for the others. a place where it was manually edited

Comment: Yes, I see it now. The *Seven* theme does not have a *Footer* block, only *Content* and *Head*. Then how did manage to put a block into the footer in English and Hebrew?